# Anyone knows how to view the nice value of a process under Mavericks?

Tags: macos, command-line, unix

Used to be able to view the UNIX nice value of a process in the top CLI utility.
I think it's gone from the top utility on Mavericks? Any other ways to view it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use ps with a lower case L to directly view current nice values:

```
ps -l
```

or for specific process id (PID)

```
ps -l -p __PID___
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the display is bungled so you can't (mostly) grep for the command name. If you first do `ps aux | grep -i theCommandName` and then use the `pid` (first number after user name) in `ps -l -p pid` you won't have to do some fancy pid-filtering.

Answer (score 2):

I am using htop command.[image: htop image]

It's very nice.

Comment: `htop` is very nice indeed.

Comment: `brew install htop`

Comment: Emacs' built-in `M-x proced` is quite good as well.

Answer (score -1):

Install GNU Coreutils via Homebrew, then use `gnice`. It only works for getting the current process' nice level though, AFAIk.